# Nodemailer with Gmail service not working on heroku

Tags: node.js, angularjs, email, heroku, nodemailer

I've got a basic email setup done for sending an email using Nodemailer with AngularJS and NodeJS and I've got the project deployed on heroku.

The emailing seems to be working just fine when I am running the app on heroku, but when I get it deployed to Heroku no emails are sent.

For authentication, I am using a Gmail address and I also have a `bcc` to another Gmail address. So `from` and `bcc` addresses are two different Gmail addresses. The `from` address is the same as the address used for authentication.

Could somebody help me with resolving this issue?

**Edit: Adding code**

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'foobar@gmail.com',
        pass: 'foobar'
    }
});

router.post('/send',function(req,res){

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'Foo Bar ✔ <foobar@gmail.com>',
        to: req.body.email,
        subject: "Hello " + req.body.email,
        text: 'Hello ' + req.body.email + '✔',
        html: "<p>Hello " + req.body.email + " </p>",
        bcc: "fred@gmail.com"
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
            res.send(200);
        }
    });        
});
```

Comment: Please include the error message.

Comment: @PeterLyons: Error: Invalid login, responseCode: 534, code: 'EAUTH'.

Comment: Well, got any theories? Seems pretty clearly wrong credentials to me.

Comment: @PeterLyons: Looking forward to hear one from you as I could get the app working when testing locally. Am just wondering if its a captcha issue that gmail might be asking me to use when using my gmail credentials through heroku. So may be turning that off might make gmail happy?

Comment: @PeterLyons: Yep, looked like I had to go here https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and turn off this security precaution off from my gmail account for allowing the machine I've got my application deployed on through heroku to be able to send the emails through my gmail account using nodemailer. Good stuff by gmail.

Comment: Cool. See the [nodemailer warning about trying to send bulk mail with services not explicitly intended for that](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer#delivering-bulk-mail). Consider switching to a real service designed for transactional email from applications such as mailgun, postmarkapp, sendgrid, amazon SES, etc.

Comment: https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha allowing login access to new devices or machines works fine but for a short period of time.

Answer (score 24):

I believe this is an issue with google account security.

- Google blocked your sign-in to use the mailing features due to an unknown device (location).

A few step to verify this:

- Start your server locally and sends the email.
- Check your account alerts for unknown sign-in.

This can be temporally resolved by:
https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

A more permanent resolution would be to change your password to a stronger level:

upper case letter + lower case letter + special symbols + numbers

Comment: changing the password worked for me. Thanks

Comment: I was not receiving `emails` with `Gmail Service`   i have tried different things but changing the password did work for me :-)

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using direct gmail credentials like this

```
auth: {
    user: 'foobar@gmail.com',
    pass: 'foobar'
}
```

Use [OAuth2](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/)

```
 auth: {
    type: 'OAuth2',
    user: 'user@example.com',
    accessToken: 'ya29.Xx_XX0xxxxx-xX0X0XxXXxXxXXXxX0x'
}
```

Google blocks the heroku IPs (unsafe), if we are using direct credentials like you mentioned above. You can refer this Medium article [here](https://medium.com/@nickroach_50526/sending-emails-with-node-js-using-smtp-gmail-and-oauth2-316fe9c790a1)

Comment: The google playground has changed a bit, but the article still has everything you need to get up and running. Thanks

Comment: i use OAuth2 and still get the same error

Answer (score 4):

5 years later, I still struggled this problem (all answers found on SO failed in my case). Here is what I did, for now everything works smoothly:

- Install [SendGrid addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/sendgrid) to your Heroku app (Free plan gives you 12k messages a month)
- Go to [SendGrid panel](https://app.sendgrid.com)
- Go to [Marketing -> Senders](https://sendgrid.com/marketing_campaigns/ui/senders) to add your sender bot, configure it like this:
- From = any_address@heroku.com
- Reply = your_gmail@gmail.com

[image]

- Generate [API KEY here](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys)

[image]

- Configure NodeMailer like so:

  ```
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer'),
        sgTransport = require('nodemailer-sendgrid-transport');

    const mailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport({
        auth: {
            api_key: process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL_API_KEY // your api key here, better hide it in env vars
        }
    }))
  ```
- To send an email now, you have to add your gmail in 'Reply To' field, like so:

  ```
    mailTransporter.sendMail({
        from: `"Admin" <any_address@heroku.com>`,
        to: 'receiver@hotmail.com',
        replyTo: 'your_gmail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Something',
        html: `Boom !`
    });
  ```

I think that's all, in case I forgot something, please add a comment below

Comment: that made it for me. seems like heroku is sometimes blocked from gmail. https://help.heroku.com/CFG547YP/why-am-i-getting-errors-when-sending-email-with-gmail-via-smtp

Comment: One suggestion: Use 'sender' email address in 'from'. https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/sender_auth/senders

Answer (score 0):

Try updating nodemailer package (using "npm update nodemailer" command)

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'youremai@gmail.com', // Your email id
        pass: 'pwd123' // Your password
    },
    tls: {
        // do not fail on invalid certs
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});
router.post('/send',function(req,res){

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'Foo Bar ✔ <foobar@gmail.com>',
        to: req.body.email,
        subject: "Hello " + req.body.email,
        text: 'Hello ' + req.body.email + '✔',
        html: "<p>Hello " + req.body.email + " </p>",
        bcc: "fred@gmail.com"
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
            res.send(200);
        }
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm too late but hopefully someone will find it helpful.

At the time of writing, [Less Secure Apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) is no longer supported by google.
And you can't use your google account password.

You're gonna have to generate a new app password.

1. [Follow this link](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords)
2. In the "Select App" dropdown, select Other and give the app a name (could be anything)
3. Copy the password and replace it with your original password

It works on Local machine and Heroku.

```
const client = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "username@gmail.com",
        pass: "Google-App-Password-Without-Spaces"
    }
});

client.sendMail(
    {
        from: "sender",
        to: "recipient",
        subject: "Sending it from Heroku",
        text: "Hey, I'm being sent from the cloud"
    }
)
```

App passwords only work if 2-step verification is turned on. You can do so [here](https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification)

Answer (score 0):

Also if your app password is in your `.env` file you have to add it to the config `vars` in the settings tab of your app at heroku.