# Missing credentials for "PLAIN" error when using env variabele for password

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to setup nodemail, but run into a strange issue where I cannot wrap my head around. Whenever I fill in the credentials as a string, everything works fine (but of course I don't want this). If I start using env variables, then I get the following error message:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"
```

It's using a gmail account to send an email. The account has the bypass for unsafe accounts enabled. When I add a console.log() statement, the password is clearly visible. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how this can be resolved. Below you'll find a code snippet which sends the email.

```js
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'some-account@gmail.com',
    pass: process.env.PWD,
  },
});

export const sendUserCreateEmail = (to, firstName) => {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'someone',
    to: to,
    subject: 'It works',
    html: `
      <p>It works!</p>
    `,
  };

  return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
};
```

Comment: I believe your authentication to gmail is failing as they require Oauth2  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854066/missing-credentials-for-plain-nodemailer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, although it is more of a work around. Apparently, the variables which where set by a dotenv file are not working there. I modified my npm command to include the variables and then it works as expected.

```
PWD=password node index.js
```

I can set these without committing them locally, so I can live with this solution for the moment. Still not sure why the dotenv variables are not accepted though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install dotenv

```
npm install dotenv
```

then import it at your file

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
```

then it should works

Comment: I missed this part. Thanks its working now