# Trying to send email with Nodemailer and Twilio Sendgrid with normal auth (not Oauth2). SendMessage() fails with Error: Missing credentials for PLAIN

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, sendgrid, nodemailer

I am attempting to send an email using Nodemailer and Twilio Sendgrid, following the tutorial [here](https://flawsomedev.com/posts/secure-restapi-user-authentication-node-JWT-mongodb/). As far as I can tell I am following the instructions in the tutorial, as well as the[Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/) and [Sendgrid](https://app.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate/langs/smtp) documentation. Every time this method is called, the code in the catch block executes, and I get the error `Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"`.

My question was closed due to association with the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854066/missing-credentials-for-plain-nodemailer), however my problem is different and none of the solutions on the thread apply. I am using my own domain to send, not gmail.com. I want to solve the problem without using Oauth2, which from what I understand I should not need, given that I am using an email domain I control. Also I am already using `pass' rather than 'password` for my authorization data (the top solution on the associated answer).

I've been stuck on this for a few days now , and I'd appreciate any insight anyone can offer!

Here is my code:

```
async function sendEmail(email, code) {
    try{
        const smtpEndpoint = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
        const port = 465;
        const senderAddress = 'Name "contact@mydomain.com"';
        const toAddress = email;
        const smtpUsername = "apikey";
        const smtpPassword = process.env.SG_APIKEY;
        const subject = "Verify your email";

        var body_html = `<!DOCTYPE> 
        <html>
          <body>
            <p>Your authentication code is : </p> <b>${code}</b>
          </body>
        </html>`;

        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: smtpEndpoint,
          port: port,
          secure: true, 
          auth: {
            user: smtpUsername,
            pass: smtpPassword,
          },
          logger: true,
          debug: true,
        });
        
        let mailOptions = {
          from: senderAddress,
          to: toAddress,
          subject: subject,
          html: body_html,
        };

        let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
        return { error: false };
    } catch (error) {
    console.error("send-email-error", error);

    return {
      error: true,
      message: "Cannot send email",
    };
  }
}
```

And here is the log:
[image: error log in bash terminal]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already identified the issue of API key not being passed into the Nodemailer transport. While hardcoding the key is a possible solution, it's not a good practice. Usually secrets and keys are managed via environment variables so they are, for example, not accidentally committed to a repository and can be configured externally without changing the code.

In the tutorial you linked, working with the environment variable is addressed, but I see there is a mistake with `.env` file. So let me try to recap how to properly get `SG_APIKEY` from environment variable and `.env` file.

- In your project directory create the `.env` file with the following contents:

  ```
  SG_APIKEY=<your_sendgrid_api_key>
  ```

  (obviously replace `<your_sendgrid_api_key>` with your actual API key)
- Make sure `dotenv` package is installed: `npm i dotenv`
- At the **beginning** of the file where you use Nodemailer, add the following line:

  ```js
  require("dotenv").config();
  ```

  This will ensure the `SG_APIKEY` is loaded from `.env` file.
- You can check if the env variable is set correctly with `console.log(process.env.SG_APIKEY)`

Answer (score 0):

A comment on the (closed) previous version of this thread solved the problem for me:

[image]

Comment: I don't think posting the question again makes sense when the previous was closed. I do agree folks a trigger happy on closing questions here. I'll vote to reopen yours, although I don't think it'll get enough votes...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Swimburger thank you. I'm pretty new to Stackoverflow and I can't complain, nor do I want to criticize anyone. I reposted the question because I had missed the comment on the previous version of the thread that ultimately solved the issue, and I was still seeking an answer. I tried to clarify the distinction from other threads in my repost. When the issue was resolved I wanted to include the answer here in case it could be helpful to someone, and to give credit where it was due. I'm very open to suggestions regarding StackOverflow etiquette.

Comment: @RyanSchafer, it's all good. I'm glad you got your answer, that's what's most important!