# Nodemailer Nextjs Typescript form not sending emails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, nodemailer

I am working on a personal project with `Next.js` `Typescript` and `Nodemailer`. It is my first time using `Nodemailer`. I am having issues making it work. I am following this [tutorial](https://dev.to/haydenbleasel/creating-a-standalone-contact-form-with-next-js-4gjf). This is my code below as it is on the tutorial.

`Nodemailer.ts`: here I had to replace the type `APIResponse` for `any` due to the code gave me errors, and `VSCode` suggested me to create that function at the bottom of the file. Also, the location of this file is `/pages/api/nodemailer.ts`

```
import { NextApiHandler, NextApiRequest } from "next";

import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

type Fields = {
    name: string;
    message: string;
    email: string;
};


const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'hotmail',
    auth: {
        user: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
        pass: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PASSWORD,
    },
});

export const config = {
    api: {
      bodyParser: false,
    },
};

const handler: NextApiHandler<any> = async(req, res) => {
    if (req.method !== "POST") {
        return res.status(404).send({ error: "Begone." });
    }

    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")

    try {
        const { fields } = await formidablePromise(req, {});
        const { name, email, message } = fields;
    
        if (!name || !name.trim()) {
          throw new Error("Please provide a valid name.");
        }
    
        if (!email || !email.trim()) {
          throw new Error("Please provide a valid email address.");
        }
    
        if (!message || !message.trim()) {
          throw new Error("Please provide a valid email message.");
        }
    
        await transporter.sendMail({
          to: 'info@someemail.com.au',
          from: 'info@someemail.com.au',
          replyTo: email,
          subject: `Hello from ${name}`,
          text: message,
          html: `<p>${message.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "<br>")}</p>`,
        });
    
        res.status(200).json({});
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: error });
    }
}

export default handler;

function formidablePromise(req: NextApiRequest, arg1: {}): { fields: any; } | PromiseLike<{ fields: any; }> {
    throw new Error("Function not implemented.");
}
```

`Form.tsx`: It is in `/components/Form.tsx`

```
import { FaFacebook, FaTwitter } from 'react-icons/fa';
import React, { ChangeEvent, FormEvent, useRef, useState } from 'react';

import styles from './Form.module.css';

export interface FormProps {
    result: boolean
    isChecked: boolean
    callTime: {time: string, isChecked: boolean}[]

    loading: boolean
}

const Form: React.FC<FormProps> = () => {    

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const [name, setName] = useState<string>("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>("");
    const [mobile, setMobile] = useState<string | number | any>("");
    const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>("");

    console.log('NAme:', name, ', email', email, ', mobile', mobile, ', message', message);

    async function sendEmail(event: FormEvent) {
      event.preventDefault();
    
      setLoading(true);
    
      try {
        const formData = new FormData();
    
        if (!name.trim()) {
          throw new Error("Please provide a valid name.");
        }
    
        if (!email.trim()) {
          throw new Error("Please provide a valid email address.");
        }

        if (!mobile.trim()) {
          throw new Error("Please provide a valid mobile number.");
        }
    
        if (!message.trim()) {
          throw new Error("Please provide a valid message.");
        }
    
        formData.append("name", name);
        formData.append("email", email);
        formData.append("mobile", mobile);
        formData.append("message", message);

        console.log('form data', formData);
    
        const response = await fetch("/api/nodemailer", {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData,
        });
    
        const responseData = await response.json();
        console.log('form responseData', responseData);
    
        if (responseData.error) {
          throw new Error(responseData.error);
        }
    
        console.log("Thanks, we will be in touch soon!");
    
        setName("");
        setEmail("");
        setMobile("");
        setMessage("");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }

      
      
    }
    
      console.log('send email', sendEmail);
    

    return (
        <>
            <div className={styles.wrapper}>
                <form 
                onSubmit={sendEmail} 
                className={styles.formContainer}>
                    <h3>Get <span>in</span> touch</h3>
                    <label>Full Name<span className={styles.required}>*</span></label>
                    <input 
                      type="text" 
                      name="name" 
                      required
                      value={name}
                      onChange={({ target }: ChangeEvent) => setName(( target as HTMLInputElement ).value)}
                    />
                    <div className={styles.twoInputs}>
                        <div className={styles.innerInputs}>
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input 
                              type="email" 
                              name="email"
                              pattern=".+@.+\..+"
                              value={email}
                              onChange={({ target }: ChangeEvent) => setEmail(( target as HTMLInputElement ).value)}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.innerInputs}>
                            <label>Mobile<span className={styles.required}>*</span></label>
                            <input 
                              type="tel" 
                              name="tel" 
                              required
                              value={mobile}
                              onChange={({ target }: ChangeEvent) => setMobile((target as HTMLInputElement ).value)} />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <label>Message<span className={styles.required}>*</span></label>
                    <textarea 
                      name="message" 
                      rows={6} 
                      required 
                      value={message}
                      maxLength={1000}
                      onChange={({ target }: ChangeEvent) => setMessage(( target as HTMLInputElement ).value)}
                    />
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
                    <small><span className={styles.required}>*</span>Required</small>
                </form>
            </div>
            
        </>
    )
}

export default Form;
```

At the moment I having an error 500 on the browser network, but when I opened the link the error references to the 404 of the `Nodemailer.ts` handler "*Begone*."
Any help would be much appreacciate it.

UPDATE after Anton answer
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need install **@types/nodemailer** as a devDependencies.

In the **Form.tsx** you are trying to send a regular object (class) instead of JSON. You must serialize the data with **JSON.stringify()** and you can also add a **headers** here. To simplify, you can directly put the values (states) to **JSON.stringify()**. And remove all **formData**.

#### Form.tsx

```js
const response = await fetch('/api/nodemailer', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ name, email, mobile, message }), // Serialize JSON
});
```

I removed the **formidablePromise()** function because we recive and handling all data from the **handler** function and **req.body**.

#### nodemailer.ts

```js
import { NextApiResponse, NextApiRequest } from 'next';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

type Fields = {
  name: string;
  message: string;
  mobile: string;
  email: string;
};

type Response = {
  error?: string;
  status?: string;
  message?: string;
};

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'hotmail',
  auth: {
    user: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    pass: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PASSWORD,
  },
});

//export const config = {
//  api: {
//    bodyParser: false,
//  },
//};

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<Response>) => {
  const { name, email, message } = req.body as Fields;

  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(404).send({ status: 'fail', error: 'Begone.' });
  }

  try {
    if (!name || !name.trim()) {
      throw new Error('Please provide a valid name.');
    }

    if (!email || !email.trim()) {
      throw new Error('Please provide a valid email address.');
    }

    if (!message || !message.trim()) {
      throw new Error('Please provide a valid email message.');
    }

    await transporter.sendMail({
      to: 'info@someemail.com.au',
      from: 'info@someemail.com.au',
      replyTo: email,
      subject: `Hello from ${name}`,
      text: message,
      html: `<p>${message.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>')}</p>`,
    });

    res.status(200).send({ status: 'done', message: 'message has been sent' });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ status: 'fail', error: `${error}` });
  }
};

export default handler;
```

This works with my nodemailer **Gmail** options.

#### With `export const config = {api: {bodyParser: false}}`

[image]

#### Without

[image]

#### Credentials issue: Error: Missing credentials for "LOGIN" / "PLAIN"

[image]

I had **LOGIN** instead of **PLAIN** because I have other values in my **.env**, you need to check your **.env**. If it is fine, in the second step, create a **app passwords**, because you can't to use the same password as for login in.

> How to set app passwords [Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en), [Hotmail](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944)

Also, you can find an answer about **Missing credentials for "PLAIN"** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854066/missing-credentials-for-plain-nodemailer)

Comment: Hi @Anton thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I still having the same error as before. On the terminal the error says that:
error - (api)\pages\api\nodemailer.ts (34:10) @ handler
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'req.body' as it is undefined.
  32 | 
  33 | const handler = async(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<Response>) => {
> 34 |   const { name, email, message } = req.body as Fields;
     |          ^
  35 | 
  36 |     if (req.method !== "POST") {
  37 |         return res.status(404).send({ status: 'fail', error: "Begone." });

Comment: and on the browser the error says that:
index.tsx?9a58:76          POST http://localhost:3000/api/nodemailer 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I tried also with gmail and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Remove `export const config = {api: {bodyParser: false}}` from **nodemailer.ts**

Comment: Thank you @anton again. Now, the error on the console disapear. But, the form still not working. It still having the error 505 on the browser. I'll update the post with screenshots for you to see.

Comment: It  looks like **.env** values are incorrect or you don't have permission to send via email. I'm not using hotmail, but for gmail you need to create (generate) you own password for third party libraries then replace your password.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @anton I need to set up that now nad hopefully works.