# how to send email with nodejs from heroku

Tags: node.js

I have this nodejs app am running and am trying to send an email to newly register users like a verification link. On my local server it works well but when I deployed to heroku it always fails.

my nodejs code

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    auth: {
      user: 'gmail.com',
      pass: 'password'
    }
  });
```

```
var mailOptions = {
                from: 'gmail@gmail.com',
                to: email,
                subject: 'Verification code',
                html: `<h1 style="color:blue,font-weight:bold,text-transform-uppercase"></h1></p>
                <p style="color:black,font-weight:bold,text-align:center, font-size:20px">${pin}</p>
                <span>this verification process helps comfirm that your the real owner of this account, so we can
                help protect you from scams</span>
                <p>click the link <a href="localhost:3000/${v_address}.verification">${v_address}</a> to go to the verification page</p>`
              };
              transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, async function(error, info){
                if (error) {
                  res.json({error:'failed please check details or network connection'});
                }else {
                    const newCrete = await Create.save()
                    if(newCrete){
                        const newVerify = new Verifyuser({
                        email:email,
                        pin:pin,
                        address:v_address
                    })
                    const Verified = await newVerify.save()
                    res.json({success:'success'})
                    }
                }
              });
```

Comment: Google limits Heroku IPs. Have you checked out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693280/nodemailer-with-gmail-service-not-working-on-heroku && https://medium.com/@nickroach_50526/sending-emails-with-node-js-using-smtp-gmail-and-oauth2-316fe9c790a1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodemailer with Gmail service not working on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693280/nodemailer-with-gmail-service-not-working-on-heroku)

Comment: "it always fails" -- how does it fail? If you have an error message, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the NPM Package **(two-step-auth)**

This will take care of the whole verification process, you don't need to worry about the backend work :), This will give you an OTP and the client email an OTP and you can check if they match and you can verify the Email ID,

[Kindly check the full procedures with example here](https://github.com/saran-surya/two-step-auth)

### Usage

```js
const {Auth} = require('two-step-auth');

async function login(emailId){
    const res = await Auth(emailId);
    // You can follw the above approach, But we recommend you to follow the one below, as the mails will be treated as important
    const res = await Auth(emailId, "Company Name");
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.mail);
    console.log(res.OTP);
    console.log(res.success);
}

login("YourEmail@anyDomain.com")
```

### Output

[image]
This will help you a lot taking care of the process of verification under the HOOD :)